# change default functionality in outlook and gmail for mail inside mail content

Tags: html, css, email

i have a mail content which included mobile numbers and email ids. it send to outlook or gmail it highlight the mobile number and email in bule with underline. i need to change color and remove underline.

mail content in HTML, so Html css may used to handle.

thanks in advance,

Comment: try inline style..

Comment: inline style not working in Outlook